# Why is default origin off the page in picture environment

Tags: positioning, diagrams

This may be a stupid question, but where is the origin on the page for picture environment? Every thing I read says that (x,y)=(0,0) is at the lower, left corner. But for me, x=0 is to the right of the left edge and y=0 is below the bottom edge. The following code generates a figure with vectors spaced along x=0 and y=11 (the top of the page). Unfortunately, I don't know how to attach the pdf image.

Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[calc]{picture}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
%\begin{picture}(8.5,11)(2.1,-1.73)  
\begin{picture}(8.5,11)(0,0)
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){12}{\vector(1,0){1}}
  \put(0,0.1){\vector(1,0){0.75}}
  \put(0,10.9){\vector(1,0){0.75}}
  \put(1.1,1){(0,1)}
  \put(1.1,2){(0,2)}
  \put(1.1,3){(0,3)}
  \put(1.1,4){(0,4)}
  \put(1.1,5){(0,5)}
  \put(1.1,6){(0,6)}
  \put(1.1,7){(0,7)}
  \put(1.1,8){(0,8)}
  \put(1.1,9){(0,9)}
  \put(1.1,10){(0,10)}
  \multiput(0,11)(1,0){9}{\vector(0,-1){1}}
  \put(8.5,11){\vector(0,-1){1}}
  \put(0.1,11){\vector(0,-1){0.75}}
  \put(8.4,11){\vector(0,-1){0.75}}
  \put(1,9.8){(1,11)}
  \put(2,9.8){(2,11)}
  \put(3,9.8){(3,11)}
  \put(4,9.8){(4,11)}
  \put(5,9.8){(5,11)}
  \put(6,9.8){(6,11)}
  \put(7,9.8){(7,11)}
  \put(8,9.8){(8,11)}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a quick comment (I don't have time to answer as I need to watch the Hockey game with my GFs hockey enthused family) but you may want to try using the Tikz Environment as opposed to the picture environment. There are many more resources and it's more powerful. 

This is pretty much the [bible of Tikz](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) and should be able to get you started and provide a foundation for building good diagrams for now and in the future.

Comment: Sigur thanks, I am actually working in memoir class, but I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start, I said this may be a stupid question. Whether it is or isn't I'm not sure. But here is my answer. Within the picture environment, the origin (0,0) of the picture is at its lower left corner. That is obvious, of course. However, in specifying where the picture is on the page, it seems the line y=0 lies 3 lines + the yoffset below the last text filled line on the page. The vertical line x=0 lies where the next character would fall +the xoffset. Thus for an xoffset of 0, that would be at the left hand side of the page unless a new paragraph is called for (i.e. if the picture follows a blank line of text) as noted by egreg.

I have tested this only for memoir class; the offset of 3 lines may vary in other situations.

Comment: I still do not understand what it is you are talking about. What off set. And what exactly are you using this for. If you want to write globally on the page there are much much better ways.

Comment: are you forgetting that the picture environment is (by default) a _text_ object, so behaves as if it was a paragraph, starting at `\parindent`, and so on.  i haven't used the picture environment this millennium ... it’s so clunky to use, and there are nowadays so many alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

You're forgetting the indentation at the start of a paragraph. For TeX, a `picture` environment is just like a single (big) letter.

I changed the unit length to 1cm in order to fit the picture in the page. The `showframe` package shows the boundaries of the text block.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[calc]{picture}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
%\begin{picture}(8.5,11)(2.1,-1.73)  
\noindent\begin{picture}(8.5,11)(0,0)
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){12}{\vector(1,0){1}}
  \put(0,0.1){\vector(1,0){0.75}}
  \put(0,10.9){\vector(1,0){0.75}}
  \put(1.1,1){(0,1)}
  \put(1.1,2){(0,2)}
  \put(1.1,3){(0,3)}
  \put(1.1,4){(0,4)}
  \put(1.1,5){(0,5)}
  \put(1.1,6){(0,6)}
  \put(1.1,7){(0,7)}
  \put(1.1,8){(0,8)}
  \put(1.1,9){(0,9)}
  \put(1.1,10){(0,10)}
  \multiput(0,11)(1,0){9}{\vector(0,-1){1}}
  \put(8.5,11){\vector(0,-1){1}}
  \put(0.1,11){\vector(0,-1){0.75}}
  \put(8.4,11){\vector(0,-1){0.75}}
  \put(1,9.8){(1,11)}
  \put(2,9.8){(2,11)}
  \put(3,9.8){(3,11)}
  \put(4,9.8){(4,11)}
  \put(5,9.8){(5,11)}
  \put(6,9.8){(6,11)}
  \put(7,9.8){(7,11)}
  \put(8,9.8){(8,11)}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg I am actually working in memoir class. I assume that if I specify \settextblocksize to occupy the entire physical page (\stocksize) that I may find the origin where I want it.

Comment: @JimH I suppose so.